# Stop Perl's `tie` from resetting my Arduino / pulsing DTR on my serial interface

Tags: linux, perl, serial-port, device, arduino

Under Perl, opening Serial::Device on Linux as a file resets my Arduino, but I don't want it being reset. Arduino can be reset by pulsing DTR, therefore opening the serial device must be pulsing DTR by default.

My question is: How can I prevent my Arduino from being reset (DTR being pulsed)?

This minimal code resets my Arduino:

```
use Device::SerialPort;
use Symbol qw( gensym );
my $handle = gensym();
my $PortName = '/dev/ttyUSB1';
my $PortObj = tie( *$handle , "Device::SerialPort" , $PortName ) or die "Cannot open serial port: $!\n";
# At this point the Arduino is being reset.
```

I know it is simply done by opening the device with `PortObj = new Device::SerialPort ($PortName, $quiet, $lockfile);` method, but I can't use that method because I'm unable to check if there is data waiting in the serial buffer. And testing for data waiting is a hard requirement in my program.

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the HUPCL bit in the termios setting for the port.  This will persist until something else changes it (I've seen different versions of the same distro default it differently)

See man termios and man stty

The following shell command *might* work - untested:

```
stty -F /dev/ttyUSB1 -hupcl
```

Comment: It works after the stty command is run, but the stty command makes Arduino reset once after running your stty. Nice find, but it doesn't really solve my problem. I need to be able to disable the reset pulse from the perl script itself.

Comment: Unless something else is changing the HUPCL bit back, you should only need to run that once after booting the PC (or maybe after connecting the USB-serial device).  If something else is changing it back, you'll need to find and fix that where it occurs.  You can run shell commands from perl, or figure out how to manipulate the termios from within it.  Also consider that you could proxy the serial port access through an existing or custom utility that does not have this problem, rather than doing it directly from perl.

Comment: If you are going to be running the Arduino for long periods of time but downloading programs rarely, you can also take wire cutters to (or if SMT desolder) the reset capacitor, or defeat it with a low value resistor in the expansion pins (see arduino-as-isp instructions), then finger-revert this when you actually need to download a program.

Comment: I want to keep my script as portable as possible, so if possible I don't want to fiddle with my PC's boot sequence. Some for the Arduino, I want to be portable, I want to be able to easily give my script to someone else who can do his own trickery in turn. So for now these are not real options for me.

Comment: Not sure if a serial port proxy is a viable solution. Otherwise I have to come up with two scripts, one for the daemon and one for single-shot use.

Comment: No, you don't, because re-running it again will not reset the processor, unless what you are using to talk to the arduino is reverting the HUPCL bit.  If that is happening, you'll have to fix what you are using to talk to it.  Unless your script is also programming the arduino, a proxy should be fairly trivial.  If it *is* programming it, you may need to patch avrdude.

Comment: At a certian point, a desire to be "portable" runs up against the way in which the arduino abuses modem control signal for a purpose they were never intended to have - the probable cost is needing a tiny amount of host-specific code.  As another idea, you could try holding an open fd to the serial port in a background process during your entire work session - if you can get that to be compatible with your foreground usage, it should stop HUPCL from having any effect.

Comment: And presumably there's a perl serial API out there somewhere which lets you manipulate HUPCL and everything else, on platforms where it's done that way.

Comment: No I'm not programming it, just want to be able to combine daemon and single-shot mode in one script, without the controller being reset. I'll try figure something smart with these hints. @api: exactly my thought. I'll DuckDuckGo a bit tomorrow. Thnx

Comment: I think this isn't working because it is a USB based serial port. When I unplug the device, the port is removed from the system. Then when I re-plug it, a brand new serial port will be initialized with defaults. I've been fiddling with POSIX::Termios, but still without result.

Comment: Re-plugging the device would be a problem - its one way the model with the built-in usb serial is inferrior.  You could patch the kernel driver involved, patch the hardware with the plug in resistor, or use a separate logic level usb serial that you leave on the pc and connect/disconnect from the arduino.  I'd probably pick the resistor.

Comment: Currently hooked up a resistor which works, but I'm not satisfied with the hardware method. The problem is that every once in a while (eg. due to EMI) a USB bus may be reset. ttyUSBn devices like Arduino will fully detach and reattach. Reopening the device node isn't too much of a problem, it is the Arduino being reset while doing so.